# Passing data from html div tag to controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a div in my html. Inside the div I am invoking a controller. I need to pass some data from div to the controller. I don't have any other html element in div like input fields/buttons etc.

```
    <div ng-controller="writeLoadTimeController">
    <!--adding this controller to send the page load time to server-->
    $scope.loadTime=$window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-$window.performance.timing.navigationStart;

    </div>
```

How do I pass the value of the loadTime field to the controller.

Comment: when you want to pass data, on any particular events??

Comment: after the page load is done.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
<div id="loadTime" ng-controller="writeLoadTimeController" ng-load="someFunction()">


</div>
```

and controller:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(){
        $scope.loadTime=$window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-$window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**1:** You can add onload event to the div and call a function which will calculate the loadTime for you. It should be like this.

you html:

```
<div id="loadTime" ng-controller="writeLoadTimeController">
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
app.controller("writeLoadTimeController", function($scope){
    $scope.loadTime ="";
    document.getElementById("loadTime").addEventListener('onload', onloadHandler);
    function onloadHandler(){
        $scope.loadTime=$window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-$window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
    }
});
```

Then you can use `{{loadTime}}` in the html.

**2:** You can avoid adding onload listener and do the following:

you html:

```
<div id="loadTime" ng-controller="writeLoadTimeController">
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
app.controller("writeLoadTimeController", function($scope){
    $scope.loadTime ="";

    $scope.loadTimeCalculator = function(){
        $scope.loadTime=$window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-$window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
    }

    $scope.loadTimeCalculator();
});
```

It will call `loadTimeCalculator()` function when the  `writeLoadTimeController` is called.

Hope this will help you:)

Comment: I have tried this approach, but in may case I am calling the writeLoadTimeController in two html pages, and for both of them loadTime is giving the same value all the time. So, what I guess is because I am executing the expression inside controller, loadTime is the one taken by the controller while loading, instead of the view/html.
That is the reason I want to avoid putting this statement in controller, and wanted to add it in each html page.

Comment: Is controller called only once? I mean when you open the other page controller isn't being called second time?

Comment: It is being called again when I open the second page because in second page also I am calling the same controller.
I have put the alert messages, to cross verify it.
Also, even if I create two different controllers, one for each page with the same code, the results are same.

Comment: Yeah I tried it myself, result is the same. Will look into it and let you know if there is a way.

Comment: Does your page loading again in the browser when you shifting to the second page?

Comment: yes, it reloads when I click the link which takes me to the new page.